# Android Studio Notification wrong shown

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

I am working on a Application, which receives Notifications from Firebase. When I receive them it doesn't show them properly. When I try to change the Icon, it still shows the launcher icon. Moreover the Lights and the Vibration are not working, also the inboxStyle is not working, it just shows another Notification. I tried NotificationCompat.Builder and Notification.Builder but it still does not work. My code for displaying Notifications:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);        
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        builder.setLights(Color.BLUE, 2000, 2000)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("username"))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                .setVibrate(new long[]{0,500,0,500})
                .setWhen(remoteMessage.getSentTime())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setStyle(styles)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Is it possible that Firebase overwrites my Notification or is this not possible?

Comment: Is your code actually executed? Maybe the notification you see is created automatically by the system?

Comment: I recieve the Notifications with the FirbaseMessagingService and if everything is fine with the code I send the Notification

Comment: Or does onMessageRecieved in the Service creates automatically a Notification and displays it?

Comment: Ok I checked it and the System creates the Notification, when the App is not in the foreground. How can I override the Notification when my app is killed or in the backgroun???

Comment: What kind of notification do you send? If it's "notification message" then all the UI properties should be in the "notification" section of your message json and  the notification is created automatically in notification tray. If it's "data message" then you get it via an intent and can use your code to create a notification in notification tray. See more https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found my problem. I was getting Notifications via Firebase Cloud Functions. But the method I was trying to show the method ( onMessageRecieved ) only works when the Appliction is in the foreground. So I searched a bit and I found out that I have to override the `handleIntent(Intent intent)` method, wich works also when the app is in the background. I had to changed a bit in my Code for the Firebase Cloud Function ( add relevant data to the data part in the notifications) and then I can recieve the data from the Intent with `intent.getStringExtra("String")`
. And now it is working fine.